# MongoDB, what does bulk find return

Tags: python, mongodb, bulk

I am trying to use bulk find to retrieve a set of documents and return the set, I am wondering what does bulk find return? My code is:

```
 def bulk_find(collection_name, key, value):

    bulk = db[collection_name].initialize_ordered_bulk_op()

    bulk.find({key: value})

    results = bulk.execute()
```

So, what does `bulk.find` returns here? The documentation didn't specify anything about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's returns `BulkWriteOperation` instance. From [documentation](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/bulk.html#pymongo.bulk.BulkOperationBuilder.find)

```
find(selector)
Specify selection criteria for bulk operations.

Parameters: 
selector (dict): the selection criteria for update and remove operations.
Returns:    
A BulkWriteOperation instance, used to add update and remove operations to this bulk operation.
```

In `pymongo` [bulk](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/bulk.html) is a ***write*** operations interface. If you want to retrieve multiply documents from some collection you should use method [find](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find) of corresponding collection. You need just

```
results = db[collection_name].find({key:value})
```

This operation returns all documents from collection `collection_name` where value of `key` field == `value`.

Answer (score 2):

bulk.find return an interface allowing you to group multiple operations you want to select data.

e.g. update, delete.

It's very efficient to group queries and send to MongodB in batches to execute. e.g. you want to increment sales commision on products from certain vendor. This commision is not straight forward and you have to apply some logic on it.

Normally, without bulk.find..., you'll be retrieving all matching documents, make change and send back to server to save.

In case of bulk.find, you are essentially doing samething but instead of sending each document back to server individually, you keep caching them in bulk. Once you call bulk.execute, driver will bundle all changes together
and send them to server.

For more information, please see https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find/